# How to override Magento2 shipping.html

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm trying to override shipping.html file, but it's not working. For this, I tried the code as below.

```
/app/design/frontend/thema/default/Magento_Checkout/requirejs-config.js
/app/design/frontend/thema/default/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html


var config = {
paths: {
    'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping': 'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping'
}
};
```

After I run the upgrade and static-conent:deploy, but still it's not working.
**Please suggest me where I went wrong?**

Comment: have you emptied browser cache? html files are cached client side.. you also need to run static content deploy command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make the change in Magento_Checkout/requirejs-config.js
putting the html in your template is enough

However, you have to flush the cache:
bin/magento cache:flush

Ideally, delete the frontend folder under "pub" to ensure file regeneration
and clear the var/cache - var/page_cache and var/view_processed folders